# Значение оператора = после?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, операторы

Есть кусок кода, выводящий категории товаров на каждой строке в виде гиперссылок

```
<?php
$sql_cat="SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id_cat";
$query_cat=mysql_query($sql_cat) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_cat=mysql_fetch_array($query_cat))
{
    ?>
    <p><a href="?id_cat=<?=$row_cat['id_cat']?>"><?=$row_cat['name_cat'];?></a></p>;
    <?php
}
?>
```

Объясните пожалуйста, потому что я новичок в PHP (прошу отнестись с пониманием), что делает оператор = после ? в строке

```
    <p><a href="?id_cat=<?=$row_cat['id_cat']?>"><?=$row_cat['name_cat'];?></a></p>;
```

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto вы хотите сказать, что оператору = после ? в строке

    <p><a href="?id_cat=<?=$row_cat['id_cat']?>"><?=$row_cat['name_cat'];?></a></p>;
альтернативой является оператор
     mysql_connect()
?

Comment: Нет, он не это имел в виду. Просто реплика на тему работы с mysql. А конструкция -- аналог echo, см. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

    Простейшая программа Hello world на PHP выглядит следующим образом:

    <?php
      echo 'Hello, world!'; 
    ?>

    Также возможен более короткий вариант вывода строки:

     <?= 'Hello, world!' ?>

Comment:     <p><a href="?id_cat=<?=$row_cat['id_cat']?>"><?=$row_cat['name_cat'];?></a></p>;

вырвать глазки кто придумал такое. почему не сделать бы:

    print '<p><a href="?idcat=' . $row_cat['id_cat'] . '">' . $row_cat['name_cat'] . '</a></p>';

Comment: @Олег Б это php. Можно и так (только не print, а echo), а можно и как в оригинале... Люди специально разрабатывали всякие asp/jsp/php, чтобы можно было подобные коктейли творить.

Comment: @Олег Б тогда уж так:

    echo "<p><a href='?idcat={$row_cat['id_cat']}'>{$row_cat['name_cat']}</a></p>";

Comment: @Олег Б, глазки бы тем повырывать, кто так пишет

print '<p><a href="?idcat=' . $row_cat['id_cat'] . '">' . $row_cat['name_cat'] . '</a></p>';